# How to remove highlighting rectangle in Android Studio?

Tags: android

The highlighting rectangle stays in the editor. When we scroll up and down the rectangle also moves which is kind of annoying. Is there any change in Settings to be made so that this highlighting rectangle do not come up.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IAaqM.png)

Comment: Hi, we should get @Nitish as an answer with more details (not just a link) and the OP to flag it as a correct answer. This is how SO is supposed to work :)

Comment: Hi @nnsense , yes that how it's supposed to work, but here I have marked the question as duplicate(not written an answer), so question should be closed as duplicate once it's has been approved by moderator or other members.

Comment: Makes sense, sorry I didn't notice that the link was referring to another question on SO. I've flagged it too as duplicate, thanks!